# Ranlib not found

Tags: makefile, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, libtool

I'm trying to cross-compile `gst-ti-plugin` for arm device but when I do `make install` libtool returns me error:

```
../libtool: line 1085: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib: command not found
```

The problem here is that this tool is available from PATH and when I'm trying it from console it works fine.

What could be wrong? I use CodeSourcery Toolchain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem. When you sudo, you will lose your PATH environment variable. Thus, you either need to "su" and set PATH to ranlib or install without sudo. The latter can be accomplished by installing to a directory where your user has write permissions.